# Cloning multiple tr rows using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I made a code which can clone a table row, and insert it after the first one.

However, I need to be able to input more data, so now I need to have 3 rows instead of only one.

I was cloning the closests `tr`, however, now I need to clone all the three `tr`'s. I tried using "siblings" but with no luck.

So the following code works:

```
function newClone ( row ) {

    var clone = row.clone(),
        id = parseInt( row.attr('id') ) + 1;

    console.log( row)
    clone.attr('id', id );

    clone.find( 'input, textarea' ).val( '' );
    clone.find( 'input[type="checkbox"]' ).removeAttr( 'checked' );
    clone.find( 'input, select' ).each(function() {
        var name = $( this ).attr( 'name' );
        name = name.replace( /\[(\d+)\]/, '[' + id + ']');
        $( this ).attr( 'name', name ).attr( 'id', name );
    });

    clone.find( 'input[type="radio"]').val( id );

    return clone;
}

$('.addRow').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        parentTR = $this.closest('tr').prev(),
        newTR = newClone( parentTR );
    newTR.insertAfter( parentTR ).fadeIn( 150 );
});
```

And the PHP/HTML:

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="text-align:center;">Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php if ( $rooms ): ?>
<?php foreach ( $rooms as $room ): ?>
   <tr id="<?= $roomI ?>">
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="_foo[<?= $roomI ?>][bar]" value="<?= $room['bar'] ?>" class="widefat">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php $roomI++ ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
<td colspan="4">
<a href="#" class="addRow button-primary">Add row</a>
</td>
```

The problem happens if I do the following in the Php/html:

```
<?php if ( $rooms ): ?>
<?php foreach ( $rooms as $room ): ?>
<tr id="<?= $roomI ?>">
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="_foo[<?= $roomI ?>][bar]" value="<?= $room['bar'] ?>" class="widefat">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Title</td>
</tr>
<tr id="<?= $roomI ?>">
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="_foo2[<?= $roomI ?>][bar2]" value="<?= $room['bar2'] ?>" class="widefat">
    </td>
</tr>
<?php $roomI++ ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
<td colspan="4">
<a href="#" class="addRow button-primary">Add row</a>
</td>
```

The content of $rooms are an array of different strings - but not important in the matter of making a new row using jQuery.

My guess would be, that it is because of the `$this.closest('tr')`, and like I said, I have tried with `$this.siblings`, but with no luck.

How would I clone all the three `tr` rows with the jQuery code?

Comment: What element has the .addRow-class (can't find in your example). What is the content of $rooms in the php-example? Your code is not complete...

Comment: Hi Hampus,
I have now edited my question to answer your questions. - The addRow class is just a simple button. The content of $rooms, are an array of strings, but not important in the matter of making a new row using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the `.addRow` class is in the DOM relative to the `tr`'s produced by your PHP templates, but there are a few options.

One is to use jQuery's [`.nextAll()` method](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) followed by [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/):

```
$(this).closest('tr').nextAll().addBack();
```

This will return an array of `tr` elements, which can be sliced to your desired size. This is undesirable, because you'll have to update the length to which you slice your array as your PHP template changes.

Another option is to make sure `tr`'s representing data with a  common ID all share a common attribute. Perhaps a CSS class like `id-12345`, for example. Then, you could filter the elements selected by `.nextAll` with that class:

```
$(this).closest('tr.id-12345').nextAll('.id-12345').addBack();`
```

I would also strongly recommend taking a look at client-side MVC architecture using JavaScript templating engines to produce your HTML. I can only put two links per answer at the moment, unfortunately. Let me know if you'd like a little help getting started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure exactly what you want to achieve. But if what you are trying to is to add three rows just before the add-row-button, this will do the trick:

```
$('.addRow').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);

    for(n=0;n<3;n++) {
        var parentTR = $this.closest('tr').prev(),
        newTR = newClone( parentTR );
        $this.closest('tr').before(newTR);
    }
});
```

I've done minimal changes to your code, but a better approach would be to do the cloning of the three directly in the `newClone`-function, instead of searching and parsing the ID from DOM multiple times.

Working example of this code can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/hampus_b/oe0dnwf0/

Comment: Hi Hampus, sorry for the late feedback. This does clone the last TR with value "abc" - i am trying to clone all of the TR's, so i, in this case, would get four new TR's with values 123, 456, 789, abc. They should not be filled in, just cloned with the correct values. If i use the clone button in your code, the new fields all have the value of "abc".